# error trap user input - Bash script loop

Tags: bash, loops, error-handling

Im trying to error trap a user input.

-I need the user to enter a file name.

-some users are entering the full url and that kills the rest of the script.

- so if the users enters http:// i want the script the give an error message and make them enter just the file name.

-this needs to repeat every time the user enters the url.

- if they enter the file name then the rest of the script executes.

this is what i have so far. if the user enters the url once it works, but if he enters it wrong twice it will execute the rest of the script

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter File : " string

if [[ $string -ne *”http://“* ]];
then
s3cmd get s3://backup/domain.com/$string



elif [[ $string -ne *"http://"* ]];
echo “You entered the full URL, enter on the file name“
read -p "Enter File : " string

then

s3cmd get s3://backup/domain.com/$string

else
    echo "rest of script"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can detect that the user entered a full URL, then why not simply strip the prefix and avoid bothering the user with that?

```
http_prefix="http://"
if
  [[ $string =~ ^$http_prefix(.*) ]]
then
  string=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

The `=~` operator works inside Bash double backet tests.  It matches an extended regular expression, and matched sub-expressions (what is inside parentheses) are put in the `BASH_REMATCH` array, with the first sub-expression at index 1.  If the match fails then the test returns a non-zero value and, in that case, the string stays as it was.

Please note that this does not ensure the URL is valid, only that it does not begin with "http://", so I would say this is more of a toy example than production-ready code.